# SQL query for something like "not having"?

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will return what hosts are missing a piece of software:

```
Host                    Software
A                       Title1
A                       Title2
A                       Title3 
B                       Title1
B                       Title3
C                       Title4
C                       Title3
```

How to query for which hosts are missing Title2 (should be B and C)? I've tried GROUP BY, HAVING and subquery using COUNT but I don't seem to have the right idea.

Comment: post example data and your query what you did so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT Host FROM HostSoftware
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM HostSoftware AS InnerSoftware
    WHERE InnerSoftware.Host = HostSoftware.Host AND InnerSoftware.Software ='Title2'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I don't know know how to do code formatting on the mobile version of SO :-/

Comment: Even it this is correct, I doubt it is a good idea to rename tables to sql keywords. And if you do, add [inner] brackets around.

Comment: This seems to fit the bill. I get the hosts that are missing that title, but I get multiple copies of the hosts. It looks like I get a reply for each title that isn't Title2. I took care of that by adding a GROUP BY host at the end of the query.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what the subquery is doing... it may be the late hour. Can someone please give a quick explanation how this works?

Comment: The bit inside the parentheses retrieves rows where a host has a particular bit of software. The EXISTS predicate is satisfied if any rows are returned, and negating it with NOT means that outer rows are returned if no inner rows exist for that host with that particular software.

Comment: Reading some documentation and examples for EXISTS may help explain things: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

Comment: I understand the exists predicate and the negation, but what baffles me is that the subquery `SELECT * FROM HostSoftware AS InnerSoftware
    WHERE InnerSoftware.Host = HostSoftware.Host AND InnerSoftware.Software ='Title2'` returns the same recordset as `SELECT * FROM HostSoftware where Software='Title2'`, but using that as the subquery makes MySQL sad.

Comment: By sad, I mean "empty recordset".

Comment: InnerSoftware.Host = HostSoftware.Host acts like the ON clause of a join. It associates the outer query with the inner query.

Comment: This is exactly what I need

Answer (score 19):

I think a simpler way of doing this is:

```
select software
from HostSoftware hs
group by software
having max(case when software = 'Title2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This does not require a correlated subquery.  And, it should result in better execution plans on most databases.

Comment: What's `title`?

Comment: @brandones . . . Good catch.  That should have been `software`.

Comment: Better execution because its not rescanning the entire table in the subquery? Where executes before group by, but its still better to avoid that subquery right?

Comment: @KLDavenport . . . Actually, better execution because it does not need an additional step to remove duplicates.  The accepted solution will return duplicate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - might be wrong, but if you want to find hosts which don't have certain software then shouldn't it be `select host ... group by host ...`?

Comment: @Sam . . . Good catch.