# Record selection formula in crystal to find people missing document

Tags: sql, filter, selection, crystal-reports-2008

I'm trying to create a selection formula that will find people missing a document name among all documents, along with the other cases shown below.  I'm not clear on how to look in all docs for that person, among all the other people.

I'm showing example table data:

```
**Person** table
PID  ID_Number  First  Last
1    123        Joe    Shmoe
2    234        Luke   Skywalker
3    456        Yoda   Guy
4               Yogi   Gal
5    678x       Mr     Rogers


**Person_ID_Numbers** table
PID  ID_Number  Document_Name  
1    123        Verification   
1    222        License        
1    333        Training       
2    234        License        
2    444        Something      
2    555        Specialty      
3    456        License        
3    777        Something      
3    888        Other  
4               Verification
5    999        Other
```

The tables are joined on PID.  I need to find the ones that don't have the Verification document among all the Document_Names. Plus I'm finding blank id's in either table, id's that don't match between tables for the Verification Document, and id's that aren't 3 digits long.  How do I check to see if they are missing the Verification Document with everything else?

Record Selection Formula Editor:

```
 //id numbers not equal between main screen and id_number screen for Verification doc
    (not({Person.ID_Number}={Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number})
    and
    {Person_ID_Numbers.DocumentName}="Verification")
    or

    //blank id number
    isnull({Person.ID_Number})
    or({Person.ID_Number}="")
    or(CStr({Person.ID_Number})="")
    or
    isnull({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number})
    or({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number}="")
    or(CStr({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number})="")

//field length is not 3 for id number
or
not((length({Person.ID_Number}))=3)
or 
(
not((length({Person_ID_Numbers.ID_Number}))=3)
and
{Person_ID_Numbers.DocumentName}="Verification"
)

//it doesn't have an Verification document at all ??
or
(
not(({Person_ID_Numbers.DocumentName}="Verification") ???????IDK how to see if each person has Verification doc
)
```

I was reading [sum on col where id number is something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085299/how-do-i-in-crystal-report-sum-data-on-a-column-where-id-is-some-number), but they talk about groups and I'm not sure how to do groups, or use it in this.  Is that what I need to do, and how do I do the group, but still have my other cases show up in the report that aren't related?

So in the above report, I'd expect PID 4 because she has blank id_number, PID 5 because they have 4 digits for ID_Number, and PID 2,3,5 because they are missing Verification document.

Update:
Right now I'm thinking of making a sql view like the following and left join that in crystal with an "or" of all of those ones to add the missing Verification doc ones to the report.

```
use "db"
select 
p.PIN
, p.Last
,p.first
,p.Middle
,pin.DocumentName 
from 
Person p
left join Person_ID_Numbers pi on pi.PIN=p.PIN

where NOT EXISTS(
   select 
     p.PIN
   , pi.DocumentName
   where DocumentName like ('%Verification%')
)
```

Following this example [not having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772631/sql-query-for-something-like-not-having)

Comment: I'd consider a SQL solution or helper with this.  I'm really not sure how to select people without the Verification document at all.

Comment: Like you said, I too would do that at the SQL level, not in the report...first you have to have a list of all the documents and then you would left join into that to identify those people that are missing the specific documents.  If you need help writing that query, post back.

Comment: @Leslie - Thanks Leslie. I'm not a huge SQL/Crystal person.  I'm thinking of adding the view in my Update in the question.  It seems to be coming up with missing Verification docs.  I'm following the example in the stack overflow link given.  Does that sound good?  Just "or" that data with the results?  I wish there was a good way to mark what case(s) each result is falling under so they know what to fix.

Comment: It doesn't look like my SQL view is actually just returning people without that document name, it's returning people and all document names that don't have "verification", which is too much.